# Custom Module Nested Router Frontname

Tags: module, configuration, custom, router, ce-1.9.0.0

I have setup a custom module in my magento store (CE-1.9.0.0) with the following in my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Custom>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Custom>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custom>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>our-work/digital-work</frontName>
                </args>
            </custom>
        </routers>
        etc...
```

I know that when I have setup custom modules before the frontname works when it is a single string (i.e if I wanted to use just `digital-work` this works, just not when I have a nested string in place as in `our-work/digital-work` - this results in a page not found.

I am new to routers and magento so I presume I have misinterpreted what is possible in the `<frontName>` Is it possible to have a nested frontname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have result in page You have to create Controllers in Your module.

It helps me a lot with understanding how routes works in Magento :
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html

Anyway You can try use Magicento1 for create controllers ;)

Comment: Thank you for the link - that definitely helps. So now I can successfully create another Controller within my controllers folder in my module (i.e digitalController.php which gives me the url .../our-work/digital but when I change the controller to digitalWorkController.php and navigate to .../our-work/digital-work I get a 404.

Comment: Use /our-work/digitalwork instead of /our-work/digital-work

Comment: There's no way of having the hyphen in then? I have been asked to have this in for SEO you see

Comment: Or use /our-work/digital-work as route name and create IndexController.php with indexAction. "index' You can miss in url. I'm not sure  You can use  /our-work/digital-work in route name. However You are always able to set rewrites ;)